# Validating input fields in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, validation

I am new to react and created a login form with a few set of validations to raise errors in case of blank username or password. On the very first instance, when nothing is inserted and the **Submit** is clicked, it works fine. But once the value is changed with a value inserted by the user and then deleting from the text input, the variable gets a value of "" and never gets back to `null` value. This avoids my special treatment where I inserted `!this.state.username`. It gets stuck at that moment and the form submission goes anyway to the server. I have tried trim as well but it didn't work

```
class LoginClassComponent extends React.Component {


constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: this.props.username,
      password: this.props.password,
      errorUsername: null,
      errorPassword: null,
    };

this.handleValidation = this.handleValidation.bind(this);
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
```

}

```
//assign textbox values to props
  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: [e.target.value],
    });
  };
  //handle input validation
  handleValidation = (event) => {
    if (!this.state.username) {
      this.setState({ errorUsername: "Please enter User Name" });
      event.preventDefault();
    }

    if (!this.state.password) {
      this.setState({ errorPassword: "Please enter Password" });
      event.preventDefault();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your handleChange is incorrect, you should remove the brackets around value:

```
handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };
```

Comment: sorry, it didnt work. I applied below code
<
 handleValidation = (event) => {
    console.log("USername: ", this.state.username)
    if (!this.state.username || this.state.username.length === 0) { //tried with 1 and 0
      this.setState({ errorUsername: "Please enter User Name" });
      event.preventDefault();
    }
>
but when I am printing username it is still as below

USername:  [""]0: 
""length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: I see, there is an error in your handleChange, I have updated my answer. You can also remove the second test once you make this change

Answer (score 0):

for this scenario I would go with function components and hooks, but for the sake of simplicity and not knowing what the rest of your implementation looks like, I'd go as follows.
Assuming you are triggering `handleValidation` either on field blur or on submit click, try modifying it like so:

```
handleValidation = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let errorUsername = null;
    let errorPassword = null;
    if (event.target.name === 'username') {
        errorUsername = (event.target.value === '') ? "Please enter User Name" : null;

    } else if (event.target.name === 'password') {
        errorPassword = (event.target.value === '') ? "Please enter Password" : null;

    }
    this.setState({ errorUsername, errorPassword });
}
```

Let me know if you need any further assistance.

Cheers!